# What are v8 old space and new space?

Tags: node.js, v8

Node.js has two parameters to control memory allocations as I know of:

`--max_new_space_size` and `--max_old_space_size`

What exactly are 'new space' and 'old space'?

Comment: I suppose it's the much praised garbage collector's free and used memory region size? V8's GC likes defragmenting the memory by moving around live objects so that they occupy contiguous chunks in memory.

Comment: These are [generational garbage collection](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GenerationalGarbageCollection) terms, they refer to small heap (new space) and large heap (old space) terms in the article

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In a generational garbage collector (which V8 uses), the heap is *generally* divided into two spaces. A young generation (new-space) and an old generation (old-space). Infant mortality or the generational hypothesis is the observation that, in most cases, young objects are much more likely to die than old objects.

New-space: Most objects are allocated here. New-space is small and is designed to be garbage collected very quickly, independent of other spaces.

Old-space: Contains most objects which may have pointers to other objects. Most objects are moved here after surviving in new-space for a while.

Ref: http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/g.html#term-generational-hypothesis

Ref: http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection